# Replace first two characters of each line of a file via PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a file that needs to have the first two characters of each line replaced. It seems easy but those same first two characters "|0" showup elsewhere in the file. So I've ended up having the replacement strings "$bp" all over the place. Any way to just replace the first instance of "|0" for each line only? Here is the sample data:

```
0|Corrupt Record|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
```

Comment: Please improve your question by posting example input and example code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: `Get-Content "filepath" | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "^\|0","" } | Set-Content "filepath"`. `^` means beginning of string, backslash escapes `|` which is a special character in `regex`.

Comment: @sodawillow `(Get-Content "filepath") | ...` if you want to write to the same file.

Comment: I tried the following: gc "$OutDrive\file" | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "^\|0","newstuff"} but that is not change the the firs two characters.

Comment: 'First two characters', 'first two characters "|0"' and 'first instance of "|0"' are three different things - which one is it?

Comment: Here is what I'm trying to change. I just want to edit the first "0|" of each line: 0|Corrupt Record|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm sure there are other ways to do this, but here is how my approach would be.

To replace just the first occurrence of "0|" and have the remaining stay you can replace it like so.

```
$CorruptString = "0|Corrupt Record|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0"
[regex]$ToReplace = "0\|"
$ToReplace.replace($CorruptString, "", 1)
```

This will Output:

> Corrupt Record|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0

Just a simple regex to replace the corrupt string and replace it with either nothing or whatever you wanted to replace it with. Naturally the 1 is so it only does it one time.

I believe that is what you were looking for. If not try to explain more.

EDIT: because there was some confusion with the post. To replace the first two characters in a string you can just do substring to remove the first two.

```
"0|Corrupt Record|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0".Substring(2)
```

Comment: Please re-read the question. The OP wants to replace the first occurrence of `0|` in each line (apparently with the value of the variable `$bp`), not remove it entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear (`|0` vs `0|`).

You can use this snippet to replace the 2 first characters of each line **if** they are `0|`:

```
$oldContent = Get-Content "my/file"

$newContent = $OldContent | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "^0\|","newstring" }
# simpler
#$newContent = $OldContent -replace "^0\|","newstring"

$newContent | Set-Content "my/file"
```

Comment: `ForEach-Object` isn't required here. The `-replace` operator works with both strings and string arrays.